# Dimensions of Ovation roundback guitars?

Tags: guitar

Ovation makes its roundback style guitars in a few different sizes, corresponding to the depth of the bowl:

- Super Shallow
- Shallow
- Mid-Depth
- Deep

I have one such guitar and am looking for a case for it, but I'm not sure which size it is - is there a list of dimensions for each of these?

Comment: The best option is to contact Ovation guitars, with the serial number of your guitar.

Comment: @Tim unfortunately the sticker with the serial code has come off.

Comment: Don't know specifically about Ovations, but most guitars have a number stamped on them, into the wood, often on the head, or sometimes on the heel of the neck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [2003 Ovation Catalogue](http://www.ovationtribute.com/Catalogues/Catalogue%202003/Catalogue%202003.html):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can place the guitar on a flat surface and use a tape measure to measure the distance from the flat surface to the edge of the guitar face to determine the depth of the guitar, but be sure to allow for the additional height of the bridge when determining which guitar case to purchase. You may also choose to measure other dimensions on the guitar such as the neck length and width of the upper and lower bout, or you may choose to just take your instrument with you to the music shop and try different size cases to find one that fits best. That's the old fashioned method.